# Text Field Cursor Top Left

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a very big text field but writing on it is not as I'd like. Is there a way I can move cursor to the top left of the field (so that it looks like a text area). Because by default it is centered. Thanks a lot [image]

I use:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="500dp"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `android:gravity` attribute to `EditText` with value `top|left`.

```
android:gravity="top|left"
```

Comment: add this line to make it as a textarea.

android:singleLine = "false"